# How do I make select2 to work with Angular 7

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, angular7

Am trying to implement Select 2 into my Angular 7 project. I followed all the procedures to implement from github. But still its not working. It works when i present some static data into it. Its not populating the data from the webserver. Please share your ideas. Below is my code

**Html Code:**

```
  <select2 [options]="areas" [settings]="{ width: '100%' }"></select2>

  <div *ngFor="let ar of areas">
    <p>{{ar.Area_Name}}</p>
  </div>
```

**Component Code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ObjectAreas } from './areasObject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.css',
    '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  ]
})
export class AppComponent 
{  
  apiURL: string = 'http://localhost/support/php/getAreas.php?areasno=0';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  areas: ObjectAreas;

  public getContacts()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiURL);
  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.getContacts()
      .subscribe((res:ObjectLoan)=>
        {      
          this.areas  = res;                           
        });              
  }

}
```

**Model Class:**

```
export class ObjectAreas
{
    AreaSno: number;
    Area_Code: string;
    Area_Name: string;
}
```

**I get this error in console:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: instead, ObjectLoan  use ObjectAreas and  it should array to traverse

Comment: Am using ObjectAreas only. I typed here by mistake..

Comment: make it array like ObjectAreas[] and make sure from web service you are getting array of object

Comment: I made it array like it. but not getting. Am getting the object from the web service. I have displayed them below in the html ..

Comment: so it won't work until and unless you get array from service

Comment: yes i converted into array. but the list not populating

Comment: But it works when i present some static data like this this.areas  =  ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5'];

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `ng2-select2` library for it.

Try using it the way it is demonstrated here.

https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2

https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2#prerequisites

Also keep the `areas` in data attribute instead of options

```
<select2 [data]="areas" ></select2>
```

Seeu updated ngOnit function, that takes the res object and creates an array of all titles.

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.getContacts()
      .subscribe((res:any)=>
        {      
             console.log(res)
             var arr = [];

             for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
                var x = res[i].title ;
                arr.push(x);
             }
            //console.log(arr)
            this.users  =  arr;
        });      

  }
```

In case you want an array of userids then just change this line 
`var x = res[i].title ;` to `var x = res[i].userId ;`

Comment: I changed to  this.areas  =  [res]; //Converting into array.. But in html I just get [object Object, object Object] instead of values...

Comment: Can you please replicate it on a stackblitz or plunker and add the link to check where is the issue. I dont think  this.areas = [res];  is the correct way to do it

Comment: Can you please tell the structure of your res object?

Comment: Try this Object.values(res), it will give you an array for your object's values

Comment: I have put it in stackblitz. plz let me know where i am gone wrong

Comment: See the updated tsackblitz.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1ejax?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You need to take out the values from the object that you want to paint in the select2 and create an array from it. In case you want an array of userids then just change this line  var x = arrayItem.title ; to  var x = arrayItem.userId ;

Comment: If i just pass a array of single item, how do i look for the id of particular item selected on click or select event..

Comment: I do not think its related to the above question. You should probably search on SO for its answer and if you cant find it then you should post a new question.

Comment: just like in AngularJs we use <select ng-model="custselection" value="{{custselection}}" ng-options="c.Cust_Name for c in customers" ng-change="loadCustomerHistory(custselection.CustSno)" >

Comment: like above we will be able to identify any field in the listed object customers..

Comment: will look into it and let you know if i find something

Comment: Use it like this <select2 [data]="exampleData" (valueChanged)="changed($event)"></select2>   https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2-demo/blob/2f3bf617d1016f6615854d4672b4a14a89cdba59/src/app/demos/change/change.component.html

Comment: Also plz look at updated answer for the foreach error

Answer (score 0):

it accepts data in specific format like

```
[
    {
        id: 'uniqe_id',
        text: 'text_to_display'
    }
]
```

You have to convert your data in this format first.